# PHP: Split multibyte string into characters without whitespace

Tags: php, regex, string

How to split this string 'هذا   مثال' into seperate characters without whitespace using preg_split or mb_split?
I'm trying to split with `preg_split('//u', $str, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)` but not to remove whitespace.

I want the following result: (remove space without using preg_replace or str_replace)

```
Array
(
    [0] => ه
    [1] => ذ
    [2] => ا
    [3] => م
    [4] => ث
    [5] => ا
    [6] => ل
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$chars = preg_split('/[\.\s]?/u', $str, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: A literal dot does not need to be escaped inside of a character class.